# String representing bytes to bytes

Tags: python, string, byte

I have a string like this `"b'\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04'"` which represents bytes, and I want to convert it into actual `bytes`.

I've tried doing this:

```py
string = "b'\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04'"

data = bytes(string[2:-1], "utf-8") # Removing quotes and the b
print(data, type(data))

>>> b'\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04' <class 'bytes'>
```

But the `data` bytes have double slashes.

---

**Note**:
It works using `eval` but for security reasons I won't use it.

Comment: use `eval`, but **where are you getting this string**? Did you happen to save a bytes object to a file in text mode? Note, you should really fix whatever is the *source* of this string. And also, `ast.literal_eval` is safer on untrusted inputs

Comment: "but for security reasons" what are the security reasons? Where are you getting the string?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It is plain text written into a file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis.
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

```py
import ast

string = "b'\\x00\\x01\\x02\\x03\\x04'"

data = ast.literal_eval(string)
```